# AssertionError when mocking java.sql.TimeStamp

Tags: java, powermock

Please find below my java code .

```
Timestamp timestamp = PowerMock.createMock(Timestamp.class);
PowerMock.expectNew(Timestamp.class, new Class[] {long.class}, System.currentTimeMillis()).andReturn(timestamp).times(2);
PowerMock.replay(timestamp, Timestamp.class);
PowerMock.verify(timestamp, Timestamp.class);
```

Then i am getting below error

> java.lang.AssertionError:    Expectation failure on verify:
>       java.sql.Timestamp(1431344562673): expected: 1, actual: 0     at org.powermock.api.easymock.internal.invocationcontrol.NewInvocationControlAssertionError.throwAssertionErrorForNewSubstitutionFailure(NewInvocationControlAssertionError.java:21)
>     at
>   org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock.verifyClass(PowerMock.java:2279)
>     at org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock.verify(PowerMock.java:1646)

Why?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a close look at code implmentation of **NewInvocationControlAssertionError** (which is the thrown exception)
then you will notice that this kind of exception is thrown when you have defined something like `Powermock.expectNew(..)andreturn(..).times(n)` but in actual code which is to be tested the new object is created less than n times

have a look at the implementation details here ([NewInvocationControlAssertionError](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/source/browse/trunk/api/easymock/src/main/java/org/powermock/api/easymock/internal/invocationcontrol/NewInvocationControlAssertionError.java?spec=svn1723&r=1723) )

so I suggest you always implement it in this way `Powermock.expectNew(...).andreturn(...).anyTimes()`

hope it helps!

Good luck!